# Обмен сообщениями

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, comet

Хочу реализовать обмен сообщениями. Для каждого диалога открывается своё окно, сейчас у меня реализовано на js+php(comet), но суть в том, что если человек закрывает окно, то у него до сих пор висит соединение, как лучше реализовать сообщения?

Сделать 1 соединение, с последующим разделением на js в нужные окна?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего можно отследить событие на стороне сервера.
На клиенте же мозможно сделать так:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
// отсоединяемся
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вариант в данном случае - ping-pong. Суть - обычно клиент (но иногда и сервер) посылает специальное короткое сообщение (дальше называемое ping).  Другая сторона (обычно сервер) должна максимально быстро ответить на такой запрос. Этот ответ называется pong. В своей реализации Вы можете использовать что угодно, я встречал даже реализацию, когда отправляется просто перевод строки. Можно отправлять текущее время.

И клиент, и сервер, следят, когда последний раз был сеанс ping-pong'a.  Если клиент не присылал ping или сервер не отвечал pong'ом, то можно считать, что соединение утеряно. Интервал для проверки удобно выбирать удвоенным по отношению к интервалу отсылки ping. Это очень просто сделать с точки зрения клиента. Он по таймеру отсылает ping и увеличивает некую переменную-счетчик на 1. ВО время увеличения проверяет на то, не больше ли оно 2 (или 3). Если это так, значит разрыв соединения. А уменьшает счетчик приход pong.

С стороны сервера логика чуть другая. На каждый приход ping отмечается время прихода. А время от времени запускается "чистка" - просматриваются все клиенты и время прихода последнего ping. Если оно больше заданного - значит нужно отключать.

Понятное дело, что слать постоянно ping не нужно. Если клиент проявлял активность, то можно корректировать отсылку. Но вся суть в том, что важен именно запрос-ответ.

Понятно, что очень легко прикрутить команду, которая позволит серверу регулировать время прихода пингов. Если сеть плохая - можно слать чаще, если сеть надежная - можно слать реже и разгрузить сервер.